# SignataureTool doesn't open in Blackberry

Tags: blackberry-eclipse-plugin

I have build an application in BB.It works fine on the simulator.Now i have to run it on device,so i bought keys from RIM,and installed them successfully.I can see three file (2 .csk file and one .db file) being created in the vmTool folder of eclipse.I copy those file in the respective bin folder of the particular OS.When i try to open the SignatureTool via command line,the SignatureTool opens and closes within a blink of an eye.Even i can't do code signing from eclipse,it shows at the bottom right "Packaging Project 99%" and after few seconds my eclipse freezes.So if anyone has encountered the same problem,kindly help.

Answer (score -1):

Quote: http://supportforums.blackberry.com/t5/Java-Development/Cannot-completely-sign-files-Error-Packaging-Projects-99/td-p/1640957

maybe the signing server was not responding in time? check isthesigningserverdown.com and retry signing.